# how to retrieve aws sqs message attribute in camel DSL java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-camel, amazon-sqs

I have sent the message attribute to AWS sqs along with body using Apache camel below command

`to("aws-sqs://{{queue.name}}?amazonSQSClient=#sqsClient&attributeNames=#systemName")`

Message sent successfully. Now i want to retrieve the the message attribute **systemName** using Camel DSL java. But not able to retrieve it. **CamelAwsSqsAttributes** and **CamelAwsSqsMessageAttributes** both are coming blank in the header. Below are the code of *Consumer*

```
Main main = new Main();
        main.bind("sqsAttributeNames", Collections.singletonList("All"));
        main.bind("sqsMessageAttributeNames", Collections.singletonList("All"));

    from("aws-sqs://a{{queue.name}}?" +
            "amazonSQSClient=#sqsClient&attributeNames=#sqsAttributeNames&messageAttributeNames=#sqsMessageAttributeNames")
            .log("We have a failed request message in queue ${headers}")
```

Can someone please help me on this??

Answer (score 0):

The config looks okay, except the Collection should be replaced by comma-separated Strings (make sure there are no space between the Strings).

Also, please mention the attributes that you want. All may not work.

```
    Main main = new Main();
    main.bind("sqsAttributeNames", "Attr1,Attr2");
    main.bind("sqsMessageAttributeNames", "Attr1,Attr2");
```

Please follow latest [Camel-SQS-Component.](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/aws-sqs-component.html)